# I try to understand the translateY calculation using offsetHeight and clientHeight

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I try to fixate the last row of a table using translateY. It works now, but I do not understand the calculation difference shown below. And for the example: app.page = 'sections';

```
<div class='table-scroll' style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <table>
        <thead ...>
        <tbody>
              <tr.......
              <tr class="scroll-end">
               .....
              </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In this example:

```
.scroll-table has a scrollHeight of 1169 and a clientHeight of 864
```

I assumed I could do the first translateY (without scrolling) with:

```
864 - 1169 = -305 // .scroll-table.scrollHeight - .scroll-table.clientHeight
```

But I needed:

```
.scroll-end has an offsetTop : 1105 and an offsetHeight : 47
```

and calculating TranslateY using:

```
864 - 1105 - 47 = -288  // .scroll-table.scrollHeight - .scroll-end.offsetTop - .scroll-end.offsetHeight
```

OK, but I do not understand the difference of 17 and why the first calculation fails to give me a good visible last row? I use Chrome.

Comment: Do you have any box-sizing resets? What about padding or margins?

Comment: I looked at it, but it's not that kind of problem. I also made sure, when I tried to find out the problem, margins and paddings of the last row were set to zero. I think the problem is my understanding of the offsets and heights.

Comment: Can you show the complete code? I have a hard time visualising what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're mixing up scrollHeight and offsetHeight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The table had a margin-bottom of 1rem;
Now I can use for the `translateY(sEnd)` function:

```
sTop = this.$scroll_table.scrollTop;    
sEnd = this.$scroll_table.offsetHeight - this.$scroll_table.scrollHeight + sTop;
```